Azure Function App - No HTTP triggers found (works fine locally)
I'm looking to create a relatively simple javascript app that runs on node as an azure function app and will eventually return a generated png. I installed the Azure Function extension to get me going with a really simple hello world app. I published this to azure and it works fine.
The issue is - I want to use canvas to create png images but when I modify my code and publish I get No HTTP triggers found and no functions are listed on the azure portal.
I have greatly reduced the code just to show how little code actually breaks it.
httpTrigger1.js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const { createCanvas } = require('canvas');  // ***

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

        const canvas = createCanvas(600, 600); // ***

        return { body: `Hello, ${name}!` };
    }
});


When removing the lines commented with *** and publish to azure function app the trigger shows and the app returns the body fine.
packages.json
{
  "name": "accelerate.ai.chart_v3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.5.1",
    "canvas": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "main": "src/{index.js,functions/*.js}"
}

Azure function app settings:
Stack = Node.js
Node.js Version: Node.js 20 LTS
Using Azure Functions Extension 1.15.4

What is the OS on your dev machine and the Function app? I believe, your Function App host is crashing because the canvas module has some native dependencies.

My loca environment is Windows. I've tried publishing to a Linux and windows function app with the same result.

@Ant Are you open to use any other JS library for the same requirement?

So I managed to fix this myself! :)
Firstly I created a new project and selected Model 3 as opposed to Model 4 using the azure functions VS Code extension. This gave me a different project structure which contained a function.json file.
I then created a new function app with windows, x64, node v20.
When I published the app the triggers now remained and it didn't break!!
